# Background Audio play - app rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, background-music

I set Background Modes in my plist to "App plays Audio"
As audio player I use StreamingKit

I add this code NOT in AppDelegate, but in some method in audioPlayer class

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

And I have answer

We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

We noticed your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but did not include features that require persistent audio.

As indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide:

"This key is intended for use by applications that provide audible content to the user while in the background, such as music-player or streaming-audio applications."

Therefore, it would be appropriate to provide audible content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

What can cause this rejection?

Comment: And does your app really play audio in background?

Comment: may be I need to add my code in AppDelegate rather then audio player class?

Comment: @user3776355 what do you see on the lock screen, when your app plays in background?

Comment: player, but buttons and slider not works

Comment: well, I think you should fix this so that you are able to listen to music and press the pause button on the lock screen and have the music stop. then you can try to re-submit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that you can listen to music with your app while the device is locked. On the lock-screen you should see the name of the app, and there should be a pause button on the lock screen and the pause button should work and silence the music.

(As usual, you should test the result on multiple devices, on iOS 7, and if you are supporting iOS 6 also on an iOS 6 device.)

Then you can re-submit... :)

Comment: @user3776355 no, sorry, I haven't worked with music apps yet. But I have submitted many apps and I have actually read the whole "app store review guidelines", so I'm pretty sure that the broken button is the reason for the rejection.

Comment: @user3776355 (or more precisely, the broken button is a symptom of the fact that the "background music" thing is not working properly.)

Comment: yep, I agree with you

Comment: if the lock screens controls don't work, and it's not displaying info, you'll need to implement   MPNowPlayingInfoCenter nowPlayingInfo and also  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]